# How do I integrate existing scripts into Django?

Tags: python, django, perl, wlst

I have just been introduced to the Django framework and I would like to use this framework for a lot of my system based Perl/Python/wlst scripts for my group. How can I take the normal command line output and have it output the browser in near real time? I have looked into serialization but I can't seem to find any good tutorials. I am  just looking for suggestions on how to make a normal Python/Perl script and make it work with a Django based web site.

Specifically: I have a script that will add a user to a group to a role for a weblogic domain. I want to make it so that you fill in the form, it connects to the server does the work and returns the output. The only thing is that it can take a little bit for it to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want do siplay external script results in the web browser? Then, I suggest you make those scripts write their results to database and then use django models to fetch and display the info.

If you want to execute the script each time user opens the webpage and display a result, use this python code:

```
def command_output(cmd):
    """ Capture a command's standard output."""
    import subprocess;
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0];

result = command_output('ls -al');
```

Comment: The "in near real time" makes me think these are longer running scripts where the browser should display additional output over time.

Comment: yea these scripts can take sometimes take a little bit to run 30+ seconds at least.

Comment: This kind of works but doesn't display it in real time just when the process ends

Comment: I believe this didnt work for me because I am usuing the development server. I have seen other posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to be a bit more specific.
If you want to output the results of an 'operation' in the browser you have to use a `view` that renders a template.

And quoting django's [docs on views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/):

> A view function, or view for short, is
>   simply a Python function that takes a
>   Web request and returns a Web
>   response. This response can be the
>   HTML contents of a Web page, or a
>   redirect, or a 404 error, or an XML
>   document, or an image . . . or
>   anything, really. The view itself
>   contains whatever arbitrary logic is
>   necessary to return that response.
>   This code can live anywhere you want,
>   as long as it’s on your Python path.

So, if you have a working python function/script you can import it in your view and pipe the results that way to your template.